Getting a console like display of print() or cat() text from an R script to display as it occurs in an R Shiny GUI
I'm building an R Shiny GUI for a script I have that is quite complex/long, but that works very well when run from within RStudio. As the script runs, I have written it to print() to say what it is doing and where it is in the process, because a run of the script can take 2-15 minutes depending on what is involved. The users of the script are generally novices, and are inclined to think the script has crashed if these outputs aren't displayed periodically to let them know what it is doing.
I am in the process of preparing the code to be run by a large number of people who are not familiar with R or running scripts directly, and who will not be under my direct supervision, which has led me to develop a GUI to run the script. The GUI I have built correctly receives the variables I set and runs the script, but I am at a loss as to how to get it to include a console-like box that can dynamically display the print() outputs as they happen.
The best I have been able to achieve is to create a text box and then use an object to capture all print() type outputs an an ever growing text string with line breaks and then use renderText() to show it in the text box, but obviously this results in all the text from the run being displayed all at once when the script completes. I'd like to identify another way to do this where I can dynamically update a console-like box on the GUI with print() or cat() outputs as they occur in the script, if it is possible.

Some example code would be helpful to see what you're working with. The easiest solution to implement would probably be using withProgress: https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/progress/
